# Visual stusio tfs file structure and excluded changes

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017

I created a new project on tfs online. So I want to create a folder structure like this.

- BuildProcessTemplates
- src
- docs

`src` and `docs` are created from source control explorer. I will add my existing solution in src and work from there. I have copied solution folder in but not detected by solution explorer. All files are in excluded changes. Why and how can I add solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the expected behavior.

When you copy files to workspace with windows explorer, the files will be detected under **Excluded Changes**.

You can click the **Detected** link under **Excluded Changes**, then select and **Promote** the candidate changes, the check in the changes.

You can also right-click in Source Control Explorer under `src` --> Add items to folder... --> Select the solution files --> Next --> (Select items from `Excluded items` to include if needed) --> Finish.

Please refer to [Place an existing solution and code projects under version control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/add-files-server?view=vsts#place-an-existing-solution-and-code-projects-under-version-control) for more information.

[image]

Comment: Ok I do not know that copied files to workspace with windows explorer is detected under excluded changes. I did not read it anywhere. thanks.